# PhoneGap 1.3 Camera Full Example Error

Tags: cordova, android-emulator

I'm a noob on phonegap development so please bear with me.

I applied the full example found at:
http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.3.0/phonegap_camera_camera.md.html#Camera

but the full example ( capture photo, capture editable photo, and all functions shown in the example) did not work for me.

WHen i click on the button "Capture Photo" or "Capture Editable Photo", I receive an alert box with no error message.

I'm running on Android Emulator and I have load the example correctly since it shows up on my Android Emulator.

I'm working with Ubuntu 10.04, Android API 2.1.

Did anyone get this example working? How did you do it?

Best.

Comment: Does the Android Emulator support a camera? Did you try if it works on a device?

Comment: yes the emulator does support a camera. not it didnt work on a device.

Comment: but i managed to solve it but attaching a SD card. so the issue was with SD card. thank you!